# Argument of type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, undefined

I tried to insert an authentication system in the Angular app. ([This one](https://remotestack.io/laravel-angular-jwt-token-based-authentication-example/).

After finishing everything, I got for this code:

```
private userCurrentState = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.tokenAuthService.isSignedin());
```

this error message:

> Argument of type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.

#### `TokenAuthService` code

```
getJwtToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
}

validateToken() {
    const token = this.getJwtToken();
    if(token) {
        const payload = this.payload(token);
        if(payload) {
            return Object.values(this.tokenIssuer).indexOf(payload.iss) > -1 ? true : false;
        }
    }
    else {
       return false;
    }
}

isSignedin() {
    return this.validateToken();
}
```

How can I fix?

Comment: Apparently `isSignedin()` as return type `boolean | undefined` which doesn't match `BehaviorSubject<boolean>`. It should probably only return `boolean`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, maybe the previous answers will do the work, but they didn't explain why your function validateToken's return value results in undefined.

```js
validateToken(){
  const token = this.getJwtToken();
  if(token){
    const payload = this.payload(token);
    if(payload){
      return Object.values(this.tokenIssuer).indexOf(payload.iss) > -1 ? true : false;
    }
    // You will get undefined here if payload is a falsy value
    // and thus you are getting <boolean|undefined> as result type.
    // One option is to provide else when !payload
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The call `this.tokenAuthService.isSignedin()` could possibly return undefined, while the BehaviorSubject is expecting a boolean value.

You could get around this by using a boolean variable, and having the variable check the function call to set itself to true if it's true, or false if false or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Allow `BehaviourSubject` to accept the `undefined` data type.
Change

```
private userCurrentState = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.tokenAuthService.isSignedin());
```

to

```
private userCurrentState = new BehaviorSubject<boolean | undefined>(this.tokenAuthService.isSignedin());
```

Or

Since your `isSignedin` is depends on `validateToken()`,
mark it return type as `boolean`

```
validateToken(): boolean{
     const token = this.getJwtToken();
     if(token){
       const payload = this.payload(token);
       if(payload){
         return Object.values(this.tokenIssuer).indexOf(payload.iss) > -1 ? true : false;
       }
       return false; // you can return false here
     } else {
        return false;
     }
  }
```